# How to get the foregrund activity instance?

Tags: android, android-activity, reflection

I try to get the foreground activity for a long time, and i didn't managed to get it until now.

I don't know if it even possible, but i am dont intersted in my app activity only.

There is no data transfer between my service and the activity which i want to get.

I saw lot of questions of this kind but i got nothing suitable for my needs.

I just need to get an **instance**, not a ComponentName, not decription of the current foreground activity.

I've tried through ActivityThread, ActivityManager, ActivityManagerService (even though i couldnt get his instance too), and so on.

```
Field activitiesField = activityThreadClass.getDeclaredField("mActivities");// won't help
activityManager.getRunningTasks(rnd);// won't help either
```

If there is any refelection way, listener or something like that, but **not a static field**.

Comment: No, you cannot do it. That's by design. It's a security measure. One app is not supposed to have direct reference to other app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing why you want an instance of the `Activity`, or other background info. I'd suggest the following.

If you're inside a `Fragment`, then you can do `getActivity()` - which will give a reference to the `Activity`, and you can then cast this as your own `Activity`.

Otherwise, you might want to consider having a `BroadcastReceiver`, which can start an Activity for you.

You shouldn't be accessing an `Activity` directly. If you have methods/logic you need to access, you might consider refactoring them into a helper class.

**Edit:**

"Your application runs in a secure sandbox environment, so other processes on the system cannot access your code or private data." Take from the official Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Dalvik)

Comment: But, as I mentioned, i want the foreground activity instance even if the activity is not my app's activity.

Comment: @user2367424 you cannot get an instance of an activity that is not your own app

Comment: @tyczj You probably right, cause i tried lot of different ways and i didn't get the activity. As i said, I don't know if it even possible... but however i thought maybe someone will know.

Comment: I've updated the answer above - RE: Security in the Android OS with info from the docs